# Are solo papers worth it in ML/AI?

Tags: publications, phd

I recently finished my MS in CS and I wish to join PhD in the field of AI (Computer Vision).
I have one first-authored paper in [CVPR-W](https://cvpr.thecvf.com/) and after that, I started working alone due to "free-time" conflicts with advisors. I published 2 papers working alone(no coauthor, no advisor), one at a decent semiconductor conference and another at [IJCB: (premier in the field of biometrics)](https://ijcb2023.ieee-biometrics.org/call-for-papers/).

1. How helpful are solo papers to secure a good PhD?
2. Since ML/AI is a highly collaborative field, are solo papers appreciated?

Comment: The PhD is your work. Your prof should at least know about what you’re doing. Manage expectations and avoid issues after 3–5 years.

Comment: I have not started my PhD yet.

Comment: IMO you should find some collaborators for some of your projects as there are many benefits (academically and otherwise) to having them. But single-author papers are fine. I take note of the number of authors when I read papers, but a single author doesn't stop me from reading the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Solo papers are not discarded although there are preferences across different countries and discipline. Solo papers will be considered for PhD application. For PhD by Publication (retrospective route), solo/single authored papers are highly regarded as a show of the candidate's research capability.

For traditional PhD application, get a balance of co-authored, first author and solo papers. Coauthorship is an indicator of collaboration and ability to work as a and within a team. Coauthorship also provide benefits in reach, validation and networks.

Your [IJCB](https://iapr-tc4.org/events/icb-ijcb/) should be well received.